# Oracle APEX PL/SQL process to insert multi-select items into association table for m:m relationship failing silently

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex, multi-select

I am implementing a form on table that allows the end-user to create a new project. This form contains a shuttle that allows the user to select the disposal site(s)(1+) that the project pertains to. I would like to use the output of the shuttle values to populate an association table between projects and disposal sites which is a many to many relationship.

This is my approach so far:

1. Created an additional VARCHAR2(4000)in the projects table to store the shuttle output (called 'Shuttle'). The shuttle output in this column looks something like 'CA-AT-D109Z2:CA-AT-D115:CA-AT-D174Z2'.
2. Created a process to take separate based on ':' and then add the values to the association table using the PL/SQL code:

```
Declare
  Cursor c_values
   is 
  Select
    t.column_value As disposal_sites
  From
     Table ( apex_string.split(:P28_SHUTTLE, ':') ) t
  Where
     t.column_value Is Not Null;
Begin
  for c in c_values loop
     insert into MP_MDB_PROJECT_2_DSITE (PROJECTIDFK,DISPOSALSITEIDFK)
       values (:P28_PROJECTNUMBER,c.disposal_sites);
  end loop;
End;
```

The process/code enters the values from the shuttle into the association table in a loop as expected for the the disposal site but remains blank for projectidfk (the key that is '1' in the 1:m relationship). The code doesn't throw an error so I am having trouble debugging.

I think perhaps the problem I am having is that project number is computed after submission based on the users selections.Therefore, when the process run it finds :P28_PROJECTNUMBER to be null. Is there a way to ensure the computation to determine :P28_PROJECTNUMBER takes places first and is then followed by the PL/SQL process?

All help appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If the form you're implementing is a native apex form, then you can use the attribute "Return Primary Key(s) after Insert" in the "Automatic Row Processing - DML" process to ensure that the primary key page item contains inserted value for any processes execute after this process.

[image]

Just make sure the process that handles the shuttle data is executed *after* the DML process.